# How to point rename cmd to a directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

This works just fine when I am in the location where I want files renamed. Is there a way to point the command to another directory for example to `/ubuntu/home/data`

```
rename 's/([^_]*_)//' *
```

Comment: `rename 's/([^_]*_)//' /ubuntu/home/data/*` ?

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter is actually specifying where is the command executed.

So to run it in a directory you specified, run it like this:

```
rename 's/([^_]*_)//' /ubuntu/home/data/*
```